# Как сделать умную авторизацию на сайте с помощью VK.COM

Tags: wordpress, вконтакте

Платформа сайта будет wordpress.

Нужно сделать авторизацию такого типа

Пользователь входит на сайт, видит кнопочку "авторизироваться с помощью vk", далее, после авторизации, нужно как то вывести, поле для ввода его емайла.

Проблема в том что после авторизации, vk возвращает имя, фамилия, фото, хеш, айди, но не емайл адрес.

Идея в том, что бы каким то образом, при авторизации VK юзер вводил свой емайл, и автоматически вносился в реальную базу пользователей wordpress.

Проблема в том что мне нужно понять четкую логику действий по реализации данного функционала. Возможно кто то уже такое реализовывал ранее.

Прошу дать совет, как лучше сделать, и правильно ли я думаю в плане создание такой авторизации.

Comment: [Плагин Social Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oa-social-login/)

Comment: Там слишком много соц сетей, мне нужно только одна. Не хочу пичкать/нагружать сайт, не понятными плагинами. Просто хочу сам реализовать более проще.

Comment: В момент получения данных от ВК, перенаправляете пользователя на страницу, например, завершения регистрации, где он вводит нужные данные (Email и тд.). А затем используя данные вк и те что ввёл пользователь - регистрируете его.

Comment: @webstackoverload сетей там много, но используются только те, что вы укажете. Никакой доп. нагрузки, кроме как при авторизации, плагин не создает. Можете, конечно, дерзать вручную, но oAuth дело непростое, почитайте.

Comment: И еще вопрос - а кому VK возвращает после авторизации имя, фото и проч? Очевидно, тому, кто предъявил пароль. Чтобы ваша система авторизации предъявила пароль VK, она должна его иметь. Вы хотите посетителям вашего сацта вводить пароль от VK у вас на сайте?

Comment: Нет, не пароль, а емайл ! К примеру что бы пользователь после авторизации мог подписаться на рассылку и.т.д Так же для избежание спама, т.е пользователь только подвержадает свой емайл, и все, остальные данные автоматически беруться из VK, и подставляються в нужные поля. Я такой тип авторизации видел на очень многих сайтах (иностранных), что в полне разумно.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли или невнимательно прочитали. Пароль надо знать, чтобы пройти авторизацию в VK.

Comment: Все верно я понял, дело в том что авторизация проходит, на стороне самой соц сети :) после чего возвращаються данные о пользователе, перечисленные выше, кроме емайла естесвенно.